# sqlalchemy filter against first item in relationship's list

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to filter a sqlalchemy query.

My table is defined like this:

```
class Classroom(db.Model, Entity):
    classroom_id = db.Column('classroom_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    teachers = db.relationship(
        "User",
        secondary=lambda: classroom_teacher_table
    )
```

Where User is another table (with a user_id column).

I want to query Classrooms to find all the classrooms in which the first teacher in the teachers list has a particular user_id.

I am able to query classrooms to find all the classrooms in which ANY teacher in the teachers list has a particular user_id like this:

```
tclassrooms = Classroom.query
tclassrooms = tclassrooms.filter(Classroom.teachers.any(user_id=id)).all()
```

But I can't figure out how to check only against the first teacher in the list.

I've tried:

```
tclassrooms = tclassrooms.filter(Classroom.teachers[0]['user_id']==id).all()
```

and a bunch of variations on that, but always with an error like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py", line 346, in __getitem__
    return self.operate(getitem, index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 175, in operate
    return op(self.comparator, *other, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py", line 346, in __getitem__
    return self.operate(getitem, index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py", line 186, in operate
    raise NotImplementedError(str(op))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you find a solution to this by chance?